# Problem with deploying Web API C# to Azure App Service when i use github actions

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

My web api is in a github repository. The deploy was working fine last year, but when I commit today it failed, with the following error:

```
Run azure/webapps-deploy@v2
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id '6556fc581c'.
Generating deployment script.
Using the following command to generate deployment script: 'azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment -r "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted" -o "C:\home\site\deployments\tools" --basic --sitePath "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted"'.
C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\296456~1.8\nodejs\build\src\Loader.js:153
                ...StatusLogger.DEFAULT_STATUS,
                ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at module.js:669:12
    at Array.forEach (native)

Deployment Failed.
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Deployment Failed, Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
```

My workflow file is:

```
name: Main - Build and deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '5.0.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'SelfSubscription'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_5A321EEB74C2465E8CD626C3DE93FD67 }}
          package: .
```

The build jobs ran successfully error happened when build jobs ran.
Specifically the one with the name: Deploy to Azure Web App
And I don't know how to solve this error, I didn't find any publication regarding this problem.
I need help!

Being able to deploy without difficulties

Comment: Looks like others are facing this too: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy/issues/323

Comment: You can try this suggestion: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy/issues/323#issuecomment-1518314602.