# GitHub action deploy to azure webapp wwwroot is empty

Tags: azure, yaml, github-actions, azure-webapps

I am trying to deploy a webapp to azure through github actions, however the site/wwwroot folder is completely empty upon completion

- Nothing fails within the pipeline
- The artifact published has the correct files
- If I manually FTP the files to wwwroot then it works as expected

Any ideas would be appreciated

Snippet of .yaml below

```
name: Build and deploy 
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main    
  workflow_dispatch:
env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: Name
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: Name\publish
  CONFIGURATION: Release
  DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 6.0.x
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: Name
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}"
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --no-build
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build --output "${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}"
    - name: Publish Artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    - name: Deploy to Azure WebApp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.Name_BBF6 }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

Also snippet of action log:

```
Package deployment using OneDeploy initiated.
{
  id: '11111111111111',
  status: 4,
  status_text: '',
  author_email: 'N/A',
  author: 'N/A',
  deployer: 'OneDeploy',
  message: 'OneDeploy',
  progress: '',
  received_time: '2023-11-21T11:17:41.9110402Z',
  start_time: '2023-11-21T11:17:42.1610338Z',
  end_time: '2023-11-21T11:17:44.5828528Z',
  last_success_end_time: '2023-11-21T11:17:44.5828528Z',
  complete: true,
  active: true,
  is_temp: false,
  is_readonly: true,
  url: 'https://name.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest',
  log_url: 'https://name.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log',
  site_name: 'Name',
  provisioningState: 'Succeeded'
}
Deploy logs can be viewed at https://name.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/1111111111/log
Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
```

Comment: It is a sample app or have you configured any other code in it?

Comment: It is a working app, as said, it generates the artifact just as I would expect with all .DLLs, web.config etc

Comment: Could you please share your GitHub repo?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is a private project

Comment: You are having trouble in deploying your  files and folders to `wwwroot` directory.And your WebApp is .NET Core 6, Am I correct?

Comment: Correct, yes it is

Comment: And just to confirm, if I manually FTP the files to wwwroot then it works as expected

Comment: Ok..Are you writing the yaml file manually or that is the auto generated one.

Comment: I tried the auto generated one from VS, same issue, then changed it to v3 for azure/webapps-deploy step to see if that made a difference, but no change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256019/discussion-between-harshitha-and-andyb952).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from @Harshitha ended up taking me down the right path, changing to v2 with package . led me to this issue [Problem with deploying Web API C# to Azure App Service when i use github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76374338/problem-with-deploying-web-api-c-sharp-to-azure-app-service-when-i-use-github-ac)

Fixing this, in turn fixed my issue strangely, I think App Insights added this config setting automatically as I never manually set it.

Changing WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION = ~18 instead of 6.9.1 was the fix needed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad the issue has been resolved

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with your `yaml` file Upload and Deploy path.

In Azure portal, whenever you enable `GitHub Actions settings` while create Azure Web App Service

[image]

***or***

Configuring GitHub from Deployment Center,

[image]

`yaml` file will be generated automatically.You can check the preview option as well.

My `yaml` file:

```cs
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - Core622Nov

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'Core622Nov'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_6C3057D1BD9741F5B2093B5402A8853F }}
          package: .
```

- In Upload artifact the path has to be `${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp`
- In deploy,the package has to be set to `.`

***Build Action:***
[image]

***My `wwwroot` directory***
[image]

***Output:***

[image]